# Auto refresh included PHP file inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a file called messages.php which runs SQL queries to a database and displays results in a `$res` variable

My menu.php page I used

```
include 'messages.php';
```

And then:

```
<div id="msgs">
<?php echo $res; ?>
</div>
```

So this displays all the data in the `$res` variable from the messages.php page in a div on menu.php

How can i make this automatically refresh so any new data in the `$res` variable displays without having to refresh the menu.php page?

Comment: you can do it by useing jquery ajax

Answer (score 2):

First Remove include 'messages.php'; 
Then remove echo $res; from div and put it in the last line of messages.php

and try the following code after including the jquery file

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function(){
    setInterval("getResult()",1000);
});
function getResult(){   
    jQuery.post("messages.php",function( data ) {
        jQuery("#msgs").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
<div id="msgs">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This **requires** the **jQuery** library. It could be done in **pure JS**, but if you're a JS **beginner** I recommend using **jQuery**.

```
function reload_messages(){
    $.get("messages.php", function(data) {
        $("#id").html(data);
    });
}
```

You will then need to **call** reload_messages, for example:

```
<a href="javascript:reload_messages();">reload messages</a>
```

If you want to expand on the .get method, check out this page: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to refresh on an interval, you can make use of `setInterval`

```
setInterval( refreshMessages, 1000 );
```

`1000` is 1000 milliseconds, so 1 second, change this to how you like.

So every 1 second it triggers the function refreshMessages:

```
function refreshMessages()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'messages.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $('#msgs').html( data ); // data came back ok, so display it
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $('#msgs').prepend('Error retrieving new messages..'); // there was an error, so display an error
    });
}
```